# Variance of $\exp(-x)$

Tags: normal-distribution, exponential-function

Hi I have been struggling to find the variance of the $\exp(-x)$ in terms of $\exp$.

For the function Y = exp (-x) where X is N (0,1) show that the variance of Y = $\exp(\exp-1)$

This is what I think need to be done: f(x) =$exp(-x)$ where X~N(0,1). work out the expectation (mean say).

specific question can be solved by evaluating the [moment generating function][1] and $t=-1$,

In general, if $X$ has density function $p$, then

$$ E \left( f(X) \right) = \int_{D} f(x) p(x) dx $$

where $D$ denotes the support of the random variable. For discrete random variables, the corresponding expectation is

$$ E \left( f(X) \right) = \sum_{x \in D} f(x) P(X=x) $$

These identities follow from the [definition of expected value][2]. In my example $f(X) = \exp(-X)$, so you would just plug that into the definition above.

**Continuous example:** Suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$, then

\begin{align*}
E \left (\exp(-X) \right) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x^2 + 2x)/2} dx \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x^2 + 2x + 1)/2} e^{1/2} dx \\
&=  e^{1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x+1)^2/2}}_{{\rm density \ of \ a \ N(-1,1)}} dx \\
&= e^{1/2} 
\end{align*}

I am now struggling with the variance part? I think I need to Mult this with the pdf of the standard normal, and integrate over –inf and +inf. complete the square on the exponent.

Is this correct, how will I work out the variance?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  I would remove the first paragraph, and modify the last question to define $Y = e^{-X}$, and find the variance of $Y$.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion, your interpretation is absolutely correct

Comment: Please, would you be able to help, any advice would be of immense help.

Comment: I thought the variance of $e^{ax}$ was $\frac{1}{a^2}$.

Comment: you are right, I have edited the question to clarify, any help would be amazing

Comment: The variance is indeed $\mathrm e^2-\mathrm e$. How do you know and what did you try?

Comment: I don't know, hence the question. I was using the form $exp(x)$ which has a variance of 1/x^2, but could not derive the variance for $exp(-x)$ as $exp(exp-1)$, please could you help

Comment: But you **stated** that the variance was $\mathrm e^2-\mathrm e$... so how do you know this is the value? Another mystery: how do you consider the accepted answer as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$
\mathbf{Var}(Y)=\mathbf{E}(Y^2)-\mathbf{E}(Y)^2
$$

Comment: Hurray! got it..thanks!